# I have an error in my code "the type or namespace name 'spsite' could not be found" that I have no idea how to solve it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, ssis, spsite

I have write a code that contains SPSite and I got this error 
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SPSite' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have tried downloading Microsoft.SharePoint from the nuget site here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.dll/ and then I have put the package in the right folder and still I have the same error

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Reflection;

using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
protected void getList()
   {
       string strUrl = "   SharePoint SITE     ";
       using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(strUrl))
       {
           using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
           {
               SPList list = oWeb.Lists["Workplan"];
               foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(field.Title);
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

after adding the package that I download in the right place I expected for the error to fade away still it's there. Help please!

Comment: You shouldn't be manually putting packages in folders, installing a nuget package handles this for you. Did you try `Install-Package ....`?

Comment: You have `using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;`, do you need `SP.SPSite`?

Comment: I don't know where I should be writting this : Install-Package Microsoft.SharePoint.dll -Version 15.0.4867.1000

Comment: @ChampagneM12 `SPSite` is a server-side type but your code references the *client* libraries. You don't need `SPSite` to work with the client libraries at all. Did you copy some server-side code and tried to use it from a client perhaps?

Comment: @ChampagneM12 you don't need and *can't* add that assembly as if it were a package. You can't write code by blindly copying snippets. [The docs show how to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code) the client API. It's a lot easier than using the server API

Comment: As for the package, it's not a Microsoft package. Someone just put something there with a name similar to a server-side DLL. For all you know, you just added malware to your project. Whoever uploaded that package had *no* permission to upload that DLL

Answer (score 0):

Install the nuget package, its the best way to use it. You can install with Package Manager UI (Visual Studio) or Package Manager Console (Visual Studio) see [hear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/ways-to-install-a-package).

Note 1: `SPSite`, `SPWeb`, `SPList` and `SPField` are classes in namespace `Microsoft.SharePoint`.

Note 2: you have in your code: `using Microsoft.SharePoint;`
and `using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;`, `Microsoft.SharePoint` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` are two different nuget packages.

Yue

Comment: In my namespaces I have added "using Microsoft.SharePoint" maybe you missed when you read the code. I have installed the nuget package with a right click on my references and then 'manage NuGet Packkages'. that made the problem disappear

Comment: @ChampagneM12: Deed you install the nuget package? I tested it myself... the code compiles correctly.

Comment: I dont know if you had notices, but I got another person that told me to not instal a nuget package even thought I did and it's working. but it's considered to him as walmare, what do you think?

Comment: @ChampagneM12: [Hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095442/nuget-official-package-source-should-i-be-worried-about-the-safety-of-the-packa) is a discussion about using nuget packages. Anything you download can be malware. Its common to use nuget packages, of course its best if you have a trustworthy recommendation before you use it.

Comment: @ChampagneM12 that other person was a SharePoint MVP between 2008-2010. SP is a beast. You *can't* just throw code together and hope things work.

Comment: Yeah man, i have checked your profile earlier, I just didnt want a heated up convo. I like how you assumed that I just throw code together just because you were a SharePoint MVP. the difficulty that I'm having right now is huge. cause, it's a code that my boss gave me to debug and I'm looking for answers cause, as mentionned earlier, I'm a newbie. Matter fact this is one of the project of my last year internship for college. So I'm just looking to learn. I appreciate your view based on the exprience you have and I thank you. @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score -1):

For those who had the same problem as me. I found a solution that made the error disappear. [Manage NuGet Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITqQO.png)

Click Manage NuGet Packages, and then in the browsing area tape 'Microsoft.SharePoint.dll'
when you do that you would want to choose the right version of your NuGet Package in a way that it would be compatible with you .Net Framework
Then Click install. 
Right after when you go back to the code, you will see the error went away.
For more clearity hit me up in the comment.

Comment: That's no solution, that's a hack that adds a *server-side* library to a client application. That application will no longer work outside the server. The docs and tutorials show how to properly use the client libraries.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'am a newbie to this. and I dont get your response. I saw that I should add a Microsoft.SharePoint.dll and when I looked for it on google the first thing that pop out is the nuget site. it couldnt solve my problem, so I recognized that when I click right in references I see 'manage Nugets' and so I proceeded in addidng the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll. If I shouldnt do this, what is your solution to make the error disappear?

Comment: Google is not the documentation site for SharePoint. I posted a link to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code) in the question's comments. You can't learn a new *complex* product like SharePoint by googling. There are tutorials and courses for this.

Comment: As for the package, it's not an official Microsoft package. It's a random package that shouldn't be allowed there in the first place.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see. I support your view. I should delete the nuget, ot it would do?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The question was not about if its OK to use library, just why the code is not working. Installing the nuget package solves the problem.

Comment: @EliahuAaron no it doesn't, it introduces a ton of problems. That's not a real package, that's the server-side DLL *from an unspecified SharePoint version* repackaged. That DLL accesses the SharePoint databases *directly* which means mixing up the versions can cause serious problems. There's *no reason at all* for that package on a server, the library is in the GAC